# JLayer sometimes unable to load resource 'sfd.ser'

Tags: android, jlayer

I'm using jl-1.0.1 to convert mp3 files to wav files for an android app. Most of the time it works fine on my phone but occasionally I get a java.io.IOException: unable to load resource 'sfd.ser'. A tester is reporting this happening everytime for him.

The answer to this question suggested using JLayer 1.0 but that didn't work for me [JLayer exception when trying to play audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381084/jlayer-exception-when-trying-to-play-audio-file)

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

logcat from my phone:
[image]
[image]

Testers bug report:
[image]

Code where problem is occurring:

```
fun decodeWavFromMp3(context: Context, mp3File: String, wavFile: String) : ByteArray{
    val file = File(wavFile)
    file.delete()

    var converter = Converter()
    converter.convert(mp3File, wavFile)

    var byteArray = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(file))!!.readBytes()

    return byteArray.copyOfRange(44, byteArray.size)    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the apk I gave to my tester. Generating the apk with minifyEnabled set to true caused the issue. Still not sure why I get the very occasional crash on other phones though.